# Why is the default value of the useState hooks undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-state

I have a list of graphics received from redux state. I have also created a state hook whose default value is the first object in this list. Why is the variable `currentFile` undefined ? I searched for similar topics that would explain this issue to me, but I didn't find anything similar. The strange thing is that when I display the default value itself in the console I get the expected result.
When I type a number in the index of the image list, e.g. images[0], I also get an undefined value.

Below I put a picture of the console result.

[image]

Code:

```
function Images() {
  const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(0)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const imagesList = useSelector((state) => state.imagesList)
  const { loading, error, images } = imagesList

  const [currentFile, setCurrentFile] = useState(images[activeIdx])

  console.log(images[activeIdx])

  console.log(currentFile)

    useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listImages())
  }, [dispatch)

  return (
     ...
  )
}
```

Comment: How are you extracting `graphics` value? Because here I can't see from where you are getting `graphics` value. And If you're extracting `graphics` value from the redux store then you have to mention it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have already corrected the code. It is about the default value `images[0]` or `images[activeIdx]`.

Answer (score 0):

`useState(initialValue)` will only use `initialValue` on the first render and does not change after re-renders. `graphics[activeIdx]` can be undefined so this will log `undefined` as a `currentFile` value.

You should write listener which will save every new value of `graphics[activeIdx]` to your state:

```
useEffect(() => {
     setCurrentFile(images[activeIdx])
  }, [images])
```